# Reorder day of week in pandas groupby plot bar

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have sorted df data like below:

```
                      day_name  Day_id
time                                  
2019-05-20 19:00:00     Monday       0
2018-12-31 15:00:00     Monday       0
2019-02-25 17:00:00     Monday       0
2019-05-06 20:00:00     Monday       0
2019-03-12 12:00:00    Tuesday       1
2019-04-16 15:00:00    Tuesday       1
2019-04-02 18:00:00    Tuesday       1
2019-02-05 09:00:00    Tuesday       1
2019-05-28 21:00:00    Tuesday       1
2019-01-15 12:00:00    Tuesday       1
2019-06-04 20:00:00    Tuesday       1
2018-12-04 07:00:00    Tuesday       1
2019-01-22 11:00:00    Tuesday       1
2019-01-09 07:00:00  Wednesday       2
2019-03-06 16:00:00  Wednesday       2
2019-06-19 17:00:00  Wednesday       2
2019-04-10 20:00:00  Wednesday       2
2019-04-24 15:00:00  Wednesday       2
2019-01-31 08:00:00   Thursday       3
2019-01-03 08:00:00   Thursday       3
2019-02-28 19:00:00   Thursday       3
2019-05-23 20:00:00   Thursday       3
2018-12-20 07:00:00   Thursday       3
2019-05-09 19:00:00   Thursday       3
2019-06-28 15:00:00     Friday       4
2019-03-22 12:00:00     Friday       4
2019-03-29 14:00:00     Friday       4
2018-12-15 08:00:00   Saturday       5
2019-02-17 11:00:00     Sunday       6
2019-06-16 19:00:00     Sunday       6
2018-12-02 08:00:00     Sunday       6
```

Currentry with help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365467/can-pandas-plot-a-histogram-of-dates):

```
df = df.groupby(df.day_name).count().plot(kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

my output is:

[image]

How to plot histogram with days of week in proper order like: Monday, Tuesday ...?

I have found several approaches: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635110/sorting-the-order-of-bars-in-pandas-matplotlib-bar-plots), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741400/pandas-dataframe-group-and-sort-by-weekday?rq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193808/re-order-pandas-series-on-weekday), to solve this but can't find method for using them in my case.

Thank You all for hard work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `sort=False` under groupby:

```
m = df.groupby(df.day_name,sort=False).count().plot(kind="bar")
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank You. I did not think about it.